# How to convert text into a CSV by comma delimiter and double quotes?

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

This is my current string value:

```
"""
    |name, model, os
    |A,"I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi)",OS_A
"""
```

And I would like the output to be like below, and eventually save as a csv:

| name | model | os |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi) | OS |

I am getting tripped up because in the model field, the string has commas and double quotes inside of it. My current thought is to regex any offending text, but is there another solution to doing this?

Comment: With that content (commas, quotation marks) TSV (tabulator separated values) may be a more straightforward choice.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input data is consistently formatted, we can use creative iterable unpacking to tolerate `,` in the middle column. As long as the outer columns don't contains commas we can use `pandas.to_csv()` to write a csv

```
import pandas as pd

input_string = '''
    |name, model, os
    |A,"I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi)",OS_A
    |B,"I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi)",OS_B
'''

lines = [line.strip().strip('|').split(',') for line in input_string.strip().split('\n')]
(name,*model,os) = lines[0] 
header= (name,','.join(model),os)

lines= [(name,','.join(model).strip('"'),os) for (name,*model,os) in lines[1:]]
pd.DataFrame(lines,columns=header).to_csv('data.csv',index=False)
```

Output `DataFrame`:

```
    name    model   os
0   A   I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi) OS_A
1   B   I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi) OS_B
```

`csv.read_csv` with `quotechar` seems pretty powerful and the code reads pretty nice too:

```
import csv

string = \
"""
    |name, model, os
    |A,"I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi)",OS_A
    |B,"I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi)",OS_B
    |C,"I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi)",OS_C
    |D,"I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi)",OS_D
"""

reader = csv.reader([line.lstrip(' |\t') for line in string.splitlines()], quotechar='"')
header = None
while not header:
    header = next(reader)
pd.DataFrame(reader, columns=header).to_csv('name.csv',index=False)
```

But this does mess with the outut `""` character:

```
    name    model   os
0   A   I PAD (10.0", 2020, Wi-Fi)  OS_A
1   B   I PAD (10.0", 2020, Wi-Fi)  OS_B
2   C   I PAD (10.0", 2020, Wi-Fi)  OS_C
3   D   I PAD (10.0", 2020, Wi-Fi)  OS_D
```

Answer (score 1):

https://onlinegdb.com/cslea1uYz

```py
import csv

string = \
"""
    |name, model, os
    |A,"I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi)",OS_A
    |B,"I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi)",OS_B
    |C,"I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi)",OS_C
    |D,"I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi)",OS_D
"""

reader = csv.reader(string.splitlines(), quotechar='"')
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline=None) as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        if not row: continue
        row = (i.strip(' |') for i in row)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Cool, I learned something! `quotechar` seems powerful

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, this should get you what you're looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import re

string = '''
    |name, model, os
    |A,"I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi)",OS_A
    |B,"I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi)",OS_B
    |C,"I            PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi)", OS_C
'''

string = re.sub("[|]", "", string)
string = re.sub(" ", "", string)

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string))
print(df)
```

And below is the output:

```
  name                   model    os
0    A  IPAD(10.0",2020,Wi-Fi)  OS_A
1    B  IPAD(10.0",2020,Wi-Fi)  OS_B
2    C  IPAD(10.0",2020,Wi-Fi)  OS_C
```

This assumes consistency with the input, so if you may need to add some things if all input strings are a bit different.

if you prefer to keep one space use `string = re.sub(" +", " ", string)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with PySpark, I am executing this example with Spark 3.4 and Python 3.11.

Create a `input.csv` file with following contents.

name, model, os

A,"I PAD (10.0"", 2020, Wi-Fi)",OS_A

**PySpark Code:**

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

file_df=spark.read.csv("input.csv",header=True,quote='\"',escape='\"')

file_df.show(truncate=False)
#+----+--------------------------+----+
#|name| model                    | os |
#+----+--------------------------+----+
#|A   |I PAD (10.0", 2020, Wi-Fi)|OS_A|
#+----+--------------------------+----+
```

**Spark Scala Code:**

```
val spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName("Example")
.master("local") 
.getOrCreate()

val df=spark.read.option("header","true").option("escape","\"").csv("D:/input.csv")

df.show(false)
#+----+--------------------------+----+
#|name| model                    | os |
#+----+--------------------------+----+
#|A   |I PAD (10.0", 2020, Wi-Fi)|OS_A|
#+----+--------------------------+----+

# // Stop the SparkSession
spark.stop()
```